# How to backup multiple accounts?

Tags: backup

I have three accounts in Ethereum-Wallet. When I go to `Accounts` `->` `Backup` `->` `Accounts`, it takes me to a folder that has 2 files.  One file starts with `UTC--` and ends with one of my account addresses. The other file is merely the address of the same account, beginning with `0x`. Both files seem to contain the same data.

It seems like it is not picking up data from all of my accounts, how do I remedy that?

I'm using Ethereum Wallet V0.8.10 on Windows 10.

Update: I added an account and it didn't appear in the `keystore` folder.  Then I deleted everything from the `keystore` folder and when I start Ethereum-Wallet, it now shows me 4 accounts. Where is it getting them from?

Answer (score 1):

I had moved the `chaindata` folder. It turns out that the real `keystore` folder was in the same folder as the new `chaindata` folder, **not** the location given by `Accounts` `->` `Backup` `->` `Accounts`.